# C# Update MS Acess data from code, my method doesn't work

Tags: c#

Hi first here is my code:

```
OleDbConnection conexao = new OleDbConnection();
try
{

    OleDbCommand comando = new OleDbCommand();
    comando.Connection = conexao;
    string query2 = "update Utilizador set Nome='" + nomeTextBox.Text + "' , DiaNascimento='" + diaNascimentoComboBox.Text + "'  ,MesNascimento='" + mesNascimentoComboBox.Text + "'  ,AnoNascimento='" + anoNascimentoComboBox.Text + "' , Altura='" + alturaTextBox.Text + "' , Sexo='" + sexoComboBox.Text + "' , Peso='" + pesoTextBox.Text + "' , CodGenetica='" + codGeneticaTextBox1.Text + "', Login='" + loginTextBox.Text + "'  , Password='" + passwordTextBox.Text + "' where CodUtilizador= " + codutilizaor.Text + "";

    string id = codutilizaor.Text;
    string command = "update Utilizador set Nome= '" + nomeTextBox.Text + "' , Login= " + loginTextBox.Text + " where CodUtilizador= '" + id + "'  ";
    conexao.Open();
    conexao.Close();
    this.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Ya" + ex);
}
```

I want to update all the fields but it doesn´t work, i saw many solutions here and in youtube but none solved my problem, and I tried very hard from myself to do it but it still doesn ´t work , please may you help mesolving this problem?

Comment: You create the command string but you don't add it to`comando`. You also never execute your `comando`.

Comment: Please consider using a parameterised command instead of string concatenation. This code has serious SQL injection problems. Also do not store passwords unhashed/unencrypted. You should also use `using` statements to properly cleanup your `OleDbConnection` and `OleDbCommand`.

Comment: no, it doesn´t chaged anything, is not updating the table

Comment: Benjamin Wegman - how?

Comment: There are many things wrong with this code. You are clearly not paying any attention to the tutorials you have looked at. I suggest you go back to one and really try to learn.

Comment: this is my code sorry:

Answer (score 1):

you missing a quote on `query2`:

```
...where CodUtilizador= '" + codutilizaor.Text + "";
```

you also have to execute the query with `ExecuteNonQuery();` :

```
    ...
comando.Text=command;
comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Last but not least consider using parameters, because you are exposed to SQL injection.

e.g:

```
string command = "update Utilizador set Nome= @None , Login=@Login where CodUtilizador=@ID";
 comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome", nomeTextBox.Text);
 comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Login", loginTextBox.Text);
 comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to add the query to the command. You also forgot to actually execute it.

```
OleDbConnection conexao = new OleDbConnection("Add your connection string here");
try
{
    string query = "update Utilizador set Nome='" + nomeTextBox.Text + "' , DiaNascimento='" + diaNascimentoComboBox.Text + "'  ,MesNascimento='" + mesNascimentoComboBox.Text + "'  ,AnoNascimento='" + anoNascimentoComboBox.Text + "' , Altura='" + alturaTextBox.Text + "' , Sexo='" + sexoComboBox.Text + "' , Peso='" + pesoTextBox.Text + "' , CodGenetica='" + codGeneticaTextBox1.Text + "', Login='" + loginTextBox.Text + "'  , Password='" + passwordTextBox.Text + "' where CodUtilizador='" + codutilizaor.Text + "'";

    conexao.Open();    
    var commandOne = new OleDbCommand(query, conexao);
    commandOne.ExecuteNonQuery() 
    conexao.Close();

    this.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Ya" + ex);
}
```

Comment: There's no need for the second query

Comment: ty , but when I execute the ExecuteNonQuery() the program gives me an error

Comment: the exception says that the Connection String is not initialized , thats the error now

Comment: @DarkSiege99 Then add your connection string inside the `OleDbConnection` constructor on the first line.

Comment: Then show your connection string and the exception!!